# Using Nuxt or Vuetify to scroll to the bottom of a scrollable div upon a watched variable change?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I've been messing around with this for a while, and can't find a way to get this scrollable container to move to the bottom whenever there's a new message. Most suggestions are to set `scrollTop` to the child element's `scrollHeight` but the property doesn't seem to be changeable just by setting it with `=`.

Code snippet:

```html
<template>
  <ul ref="messages">
    <li v-for="msg in ROUND_MESSAGES" :key="msg.text">
      {{ msg.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('sessionStorage', ['ROUND_MESSAGES']),
  },

  watch: {
    ROUND_MESSAGES() {
      console.log(this.$refs.messages.scrollTop); // returns 0
      this.$refs.messages.scrollTop += 50
      console.log(this.$refs.messages.scrollTop); // returns 0
    }
  },
}  
</script>
```

Parent holding this components

```html
<v-row class="content-panel messages-container text-left">
  <v-col class="my-0 py-0 pl-0">
    <MessagesWindow />
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Style:

```css
.messages-container {
    overflow: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 642px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: What is `ROUND_MESSAGES`? Is it tracked [properly by Vue](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). Also, do you have a [repro] for this one? I've got [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a8816585%20scroll) related to scrolling, maybe some of them may be interesting. Otherwise, you could maybe also reverse it and print the latest messages on top rather than from the bottom. Otherwise, looking at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), your code should work properly.